# can't seem to compile java code with changes to bouncycastle

Tags: java, bouncycastle

So I have a Java file that's doing, among other things, `Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());`. I also have the BouncyCastle source code in the same directory as that file - in `./org/bouncycastle`.

I modified `./org/bouncycastle/jce/provider/BouncyCastleProvider.java` to do `System.out.println("this far")` in the constructor, after `super(PROVIDER_NAME, 1.55, info)` and it's not being called and I don't know why.

When I try to compile the script I get this:

```
Note: .\org\bouncycastle\jce\provider\BouncyCastleProvider.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

If I do it with `Xlint:unchecked` I get this:

```
.\org\bouncycastle\jce\provider\BouncyCastleProvider.java:124: warning: [unchecked] unchecked method invocation: method doPrivileged in class AccessController is applied to given type
        AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction()
                                     ^
  required: PrivilegedAction<T>
  found: <anonymous PrivilegedAction>
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in method <T>doPrivileged(PrivilegedAction<T>)
.\org\bouncycastle\jce\provider\BouncyCastleProvider.java:124: warning: [unchecked] unchecked conversion
        AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction()
                                      ^
  required: PrivilegedAction<T>
  found:    <anonymous PrivilegedAction>
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in method <T>doPrivileged(PrivilegedAction<T>)
.\org\bouncycastle\jce\provider\BouncyCastleProvider.java:265: warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to put(K,V) as a member of the raw type Map
            keyInfoConverters.put(oid, keyInfoConverter);
                                 ^
  where K,V are type-variables:
    K extends Object declared in interface Map
    V extends Object declared in interface Map
3 warnings
```

I don't know what to do about that. Subsequent attempts to compile the program work without issue (unless I either go into the directory and delete BouncyCastleProvider.class or make a change to BouncyCastleProvider.java) but the when I actually run the Java program the `this far` line doesn't get printed out.

Any ideas?

Comment: Warnings are not errors, and don't prevent compilation.  I would guess that an exception is thrown in the super constructor, before your println is reached, and you are catching the exception but not logging it.  Put a breakpoint where you call the constructor and step through until you see the error (or log the exception).

Comment: I'll add to @dsh and suggest that the lint warnings are _nothing_ to do with your change, since the compiler isn't warning about the particular `this far` line. If you're not getting `this far` to print when you run the program, then my first guess (beyond the code being "wrong", and we can't tell that from what you've provided above - but I'll assume it's good code because it's a pretty simple change) would be that the compiler is not choosing to include the modified file. Or maybe you're simply not allowed to call `System` commands from within the BouncyCastle context?

Comment: In addition to @dsh's point, with Oracle's JVM you can't modify the source code of a JCE provider. Providers are signed, and signatures are checked at runtime.